# Spring AOP-dynamic pointcuts

Tags: spring, spring-aop, pointcuts

What is de purpose of **CONTROLFLOWPOINTCUTS**, for what purpose it is intended for, where and all it can be used?

What are the advantages of dynamic pointcuts??

Explain CONTROLFLOW POINTCUT with an example, where it is configured in XML file(decoupled from source)

Comment: Homework? ...Anyway, [have you tried Google?](http://www.google.com/search?q=aop+CONTROLFLOW+POINTCUT)

Comment: @Peter all of the results returned by that search are miserable.

Comment: @Sean, including the relevant chapter of the Spring reference?

Comment: @Peter maybe you get better results as I do (this is really possible for various reasons) but I get a link to the reference of Spring 1.2 (we have 3.0.x now) and one to Spring.net . I'd hardly call either of them relevant

Comment: This is the current version of the reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: @Sean, good point, I missed the version. I believe though that the definition and purpose of pointcuts hasn't changed much since Spring 1.2, so the old reference may still help the OP in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework, and I don't want to do that for you, but:

AspectJ / Spring AOP resources on the web are miserable.

Try if you can get a hard or digital copy of [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) somewhere, it includes explanations of the `cflow` and `cflobelow` pointcuts.

Otherwise, here's a definition from the [AspectJ Quick Reference](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf):

```
cflow ( call(void Figure.move()) )
```

> any join point in the control flow of
>   each call to void  Figure.move(). 
>   This includes the call itself.

```
cflowbelow ( call(void Figure.move()) )
```

> any join point below the control flow
>   of each call to void  Figure.move(). 
>   This does not include the call.

Comment: I'm not able to find any codes for CONTROLFLOWPOINTCUTS implemented  using XML, totally decoupled from the code... can you provide some links....